# My code removes all the occurrence of "1" in the string, but I was expecting to remove the counter if the counter is 1?

Tags: python, project

So, I am making a code/project that counts the occurrence of a character (repeated in a row) then reset the counter to 1 if the next character doesn't equal to the current character, and each character has a number next to it, which is the "counter" of the curremt character...

It works as expected, but now I want the program to remove the counter if the counter is 1(for example, hello would return hel2o).. But instead, it removes all the occurrence of "1" in the string:

```
t

ext = "aaabbbabcccc"+ " " #I added space in case it does not get the last character of the string!

counter = 0

n = ""

decom = ""

for x in range(0,len(text)):

    if text[x] == text[x-1]:

        counter+=1; 

    else:

         counter=1     

    decom+=f"{text[x]}{str(counter)}"if x+1!=len(text) and text[x]!=text[x+1] else ""

    if counter==1:

      n = decom.replace(str(counter),"")

print("With 1 not removed:")

print(decom.strip()) #This one calculates more accurate than the one with 1 removed

print("With 1 removed:")

print(n.strip()) #This one removes all the ones in the code..
```

Is there a way to remove the counter if the counter is equal to 1, instead of removing all the occurrences of "1" in the string(ex: if h is repeated 14 times in a row, it returns h4 but I was expecting to see h14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to solve these types of problems using a regex replacement approach:

```py
import re

def repl(m):
    return m.group()[0] + str(len(m.group()))

inp = "hello world"
output = re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', repl, inp, flags=re.I)
print(output)  # hel2o world
```

The regex pattern `([a-z])\1+` matches any single letter (and captures it in `\1`), followed by that same character one or more times.  We replace such matches by the letter followed by the number of occurrences.

Comment: That works, thanks for your suggestions and answers! Appreciate it. Didn't know that we could use regular expression for this!